# The delete function doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, kotlin

If I select an item that I want to delete from the recycling review, I want the ID corresponding to that item to be included in the view model. Also, if there are multiple items that I want to delete, I want to delete them by sending them to a server by entering a function. But I have to press the delete button to delete it. I haven't gone to the process of connecting to the server yet, but there is a problem that the ui doesn't change at all. I tried, but it didn't work out. Please help me

Below is my code
`LikeViewModel`

```
class LikeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _activityList = MutableLiveData<List<Activity>>(mutableListOf())
    private val _isEdit = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val _isSelected = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val _selectedIds = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Int>>()

    val activityList: LiveData<List<Activity>>
        get() = _activityList

    val isEdit: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isEdit
    val isSelected: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isSelected

    val selectedIds: LiveData<MutableList<Int>> = _selectedIds

    init {
        getLikeActivityList()
        _isEdit.value = false
        _isSelected.value = false
        _selectedIds.value = emptyList<Int>().toMutableList()
    }

    fun setItemsSelected(id: Int): Int {
        val selectedIdsList = _selectedIds.value ?: mutableListOf()

        if (selectedIdsList.contains(id)) {
        } else {
            selectedIdsList.add(id)
        }
        return id
    }

    fun getSelectedIdsCount(id: Int): Int {
        val selectedIdsList = _selectedIds.value ?: mutableListOf()
        return selectedIdsList.size
    }

    fun updateEditView() {
        _isEdit.value = _isEdit.value?.not()
    }

    private fun getLikeActivityList() {
        val mainList = listOf(
            Activity(
                id = 1,
                background = R.drawable.img_explore_background,
                title = "tour",
                category = "career",
                date = "%s-%s",
                liked = true
            ),
            Activity(
                id = 2,
                background = R.drawable.img_explore_background,
                title = "tour",
                category = "career",
                date = "%s-%s",
                liked = true
            ),
            Activity(
                id = 3,
                background = R.drawable.img_explore_background,
                title = "tour",
                category = "career",
                date = "%s-%s",
                liked = true
            ),
            Activity(
                id = 4,
                background = R.drawable.img_explore_background,
                title = "tour",
                category = "career",
                date = "%s-%s",
                liked = true
            )
        )
        _activityList.value = mainList
    }
}
```

`fragment_like`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.~.main.like.LikeViewModel" />

        <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
            style="@style/BodyMedium16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sel_like_edit_btn"
            android:enabled="@{vm.selectedIds.size() >= 1}"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            android:text="@string/like_delete_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/gray050"
            android:visibility="@{vm.isEdit() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

`item_like_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="data"
            type="com.~.domain.model.Activity" />

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.~.presentation.main.like.LikeViewModel" />

        <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_like_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="236dp"
        isSelected="@{vm.isSelected}"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
        android:onClick="@{() -> vm.setItemsSelected(1)}"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_like_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_gray050_fill_15_rect"
            android:clickable="true"
            isSelected="@{vm.isSelected}"
            android:contentDescription="@string/recycler_contentdescription"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_like_category"
            style="@style/CaptionMedium12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_purple500_fill_49_rect"
            android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
            android:paddingVertical="3dp"
            android:text="@string/explore_activity"
            android:textColor="@color/gray050"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_explore_liked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sel_search_drawable_bnv_like_icon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_like_content_title"
            style="@style/BodyBold16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:text="@string/explore_content_title"
            android:textColor="@color/gray800"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_like_category" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_like_date"
            style="@style/CaptionMedium10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/explore_date"
            android:textColor="@color/gray400"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_like_content_title" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_like_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="28dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_contentdescription"
            android:src="@drawable/img_explore_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_like_checked_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_gray900_40_fill_15_rect"
            android:contentDescription="@string/recycler_contentdescription"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="@{vm.isSelected() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_like_checked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_like_checked"
            android:visibility="@{vm.isSelected() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

`MainViewModel`

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    private val _isBnvVisible = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isBnvVisible: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isBnvVisible

    init {
        _isBnvVisible.value = false
        showBottomNavigation()
        hideBottomNavigation()
        updateaBnvView()
    }

    fun updateaBnvView() {
        _isBnvVisible.value = _isBnvVisible.value?.not()
    }

    fun showBottomNavigation() {
        _isBnvVisible.value = true
    }

    fun hideBottomNavigation() {
        _isBnvVisible.value = false
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your delete method?

Comment: I don't know how to make delete logic in view model. I want to solve it within the view model, but can't I do that?(In addition, the MainViewModel code is also uploaded.)